# Why the title is showing the record ID number when I edit a form in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have been using Odoo for developing modules. I need to ask that when I try to edit a form after saving, I see a form id num with the model name on top of the form.

[image]

Like the one shown in the screenshot. "hr.visa.request,1" is being shown on top which is the name of the model. I cant do anything with the model name because it has to be given in the form view. I dont know what I am doing wrong here. PLz guide me on this. Thanks n Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have a table without a `name` field. You need to define the `_rec_name` attribute of the model. `_rec_name` takes as default the field `name` and if this does not exist it does not take anything unless you specify it. For instance if you need to see the field phone you must write:

`_rec_name = 'phone'`

In case you want a `_rec_name` depending on anything you need to change the function `name_get()`

Comment: I tried to use a field with as 'rec_name'='empl_name' , but how to use name_get, I have no idea of it

Comment: Be careful, use `_rec_name` instead `rec_name`. If you want to use name_get you have an example [here](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/addons/event/event.py#L201). You should return a list of tuples: [(id1, 'first rec name'), (id2, 'second rec name')]

Comment: is there a way that i dont have to use name_get

Comment: You have those three ways to do it: using the field `name` in your model, the attribute `_rec_name`, or the `name_get` function