# Odoo: Error404 when linking many2one to other model?

Tags: python, odoo

I've made a custom module in Odoo where I can enter 2 fields.
Now I want to inherit a dropdown field (with the choices entered in one of those 2 fields in the custom module) in the invoice module.
Therefore I think I need a many2one and link it to the custom module.
When I do so, I keep getting the error "NotFound: 404: Not found.

I am pretty sure it's in the many2one line because when I uncomment the line above and comment the many2one line the error is gone.

The screenshot of the relevant code + the error:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ykkowp.jpg

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?
Will this way of coding this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a module which adds a new model with a `char` and an `integer`.

Now you have created another module (am I right?) which modifies the model `account_invoice` and adds to it a new `many2one` field pointing to the model you created in the other module.

Be sure that the module which adds the `many2one` field depends on your first module in its `__openerp__.py` file.

```
'depends': [
    'instellingen',  # Is that your first module name?
],
```

Comment: That is correct. So in the module where I modify the account.invoice, i need to add the module name "instellingen" to the depends?
I did so but now i get a new error: http://oi59.tinypic.com/9tjr44.jpg

Comment: If you don't do that, your module `module1` won't work ever, because it depends on the model created in `instellingen`. Then, let's see if that solves the problem or there is still anything else.

Comment: Your `many2one` field must be `Many2one` (note the capital letter).

Comment: I already figured that out. That is when the 404 erro went away. I also inserted 'instellingen' in the depends of module1.
Now i still have the IntegrityError... I think this has something to do with my tables.
'IntegrityError: insert or update on table "account_invoice" violates foreign key constraint "account_invoice_levertermijnEenheid_fkey"'
I think something is mixed up between the tables of those 2 modules?

Comment: Go to PostgreSQL and remove the table `levertermijn`: `drop table levertermijn;`. Then restart Odoo and update your modules both.

Comment: I solved it. I changed:
levertermijnEenheid = fields.Many2one('levertermijn', 'Levertermijn Eenheid')
into:
Eenheid = fields.Many2one('levertermijn', 'Levertermijn Eenheid')

I'm not sure why it works now, I think because in module instellingen, the field is also called "Eenheid":
Eenheid = fields.Char(size=(10))

It's not showing the correct values but i'll figure it out :)
Thanks alot for your help forvas!

Comment: It sounds weird because it shouldn't be a problem (you can put the same name to fields which are in different models, no matter if there is a relationship between them). Anyway, I'm glad I've helped you. Don't forget to mark the question as answered, thank you!

Comment: I thought i'd figure out how to show names instead of id's, but i couldn't.
I looked it up and saw 2 options, rename the column you want to display to "name". The second option: use _rec_name to change the column to display.
Since I don't want to rename because it makes no sense in my opinion, I'd like to go for the second option.
I inserted the _rec_name but Odoo still shows the id's. What am I doing wrong?
Screenshot: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2wqb9s0.jpg

Comment: This is a different question from the first one, you should open another post to ask it. Anyway, you can't put in `_rec_name` a `Many2one` field, because in your case it should be something like `_rec_name = Eenheid.Eenheid` . If this does not work, you must override the function `name_get` of the model account.invoice. [See an example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267175/avoid-form-id-number-when-edit-form-in-odoo-8/31269431#31269431)